# How the function will be separate the spread operators and rest operators

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Here is my code. I am passing the arguments to the function 
in that case the function is uses spread operators and rest operators in function how the function able to assign the specific values to rest and spread operators ?

```
function multiply(multiplier , ...theArgs){
    return theArgs.map(function(element){
        console.log( multiplier*element);
    });
}

var arr = multiply(2,1,2,3);
```

Here how can the function knows the  ...theArgs has value of 1,2,3 ?

Comment: The first argument is multiplier obviously.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified only one parameter in the function and remaining parameters are represented by the rest parameters that is why the value of `2` is passed by value into `multiplier` and remaining values are passed into the parameter `theArgs`.

Similarly, if you mention two or more parameter names before the rest parameter then the respective values are passed into those parameters. Example:

```
  function multiply(multiplier1, multiplier2, ...theArgs){
  }

   var arr = multiply(2,1,2,3);
```

Then, `multiplier1` will have the value `2`, `multiplier2` will have the value `1` and `theArgs` will hold the values as an array `[2,3]`